# data-entry intensive intranet application using Microsoft tools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

before getting on to actual problem bit of back ground on the app, the app we are working in is a state flow single model App For example we will be using same Domain model at different state of the application. at every state each fields can be in read only, read write or invisible state however all the fields are required at each state to perform business logic

if you want more concrete example think off this app as Microsoft TFS Web Access. I am feeling sorry for my self :(

App is Currently written in MS Info Path Form (please don't ask Grrr...)and we are sick and tired off maintaining it.

now the problem...

currently in Info Path Form we use different "views" to make fields read only, rewritable or invisible for different states. which creates a lot off work even if we simply wants to add one new field (we have to update every single view)

All of my team members are recommending ASP.NET MVC & JQuery for rewrite however I personally think MVC will create same problems we are currently experiencing (lots of different Views to make fields read only, rewritable or invisible for different states)

we have limited number of choices... we are strictly .net Shop, we have already ruled out silver light, WPF and windows Apps  and choosing web forms is also seams very unlikely...

is its just me or there is any body else think that MVC is not the right framework for this APP???

if MVC is not the right Framework then do we have any other choices left?

Comment: The description of your application is so poor that drawing any conclusions about which framework would be good or bad for it would be speculation.

Comment: if you want more concrete example think off this app as Microsoft TFS Web Access

Answer (score 1):

Quite a contrary, MVC is quite suited for the task and your problem of

> lots of different Views to make fields
>   read only, rewritable or invisible for
>   different states

can be probably quite easily solved with one view and different templates.

The problem is not really related to the UI framework which you will use: it's not like you will solve it just by using WebForms or Grails.

If most of your developers are happy with MVC than go for it. MVC is a good tool that help to separate the interface from the logic and display / editor templates should be helpful.

Comment: if you want more concrete example think off this app as Microsoft TFS Web Access... can be probably quite easily solved with one view and different templates???

Comment: @h_power11 - you didn't give many details in your question. I was thinking more of CRM Dynamics...

Answer (score 0):

While ASP.NET MVC will certainly work for your application, you may want to take a look at [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata).  From your description, it sounds like it would be a good fit for your project (an application geared primarily towards data entry, without overly complex business logic).

Answer (score -1):

I have worked on data-entry intensive (millions of records per day) apps for several years (over a decade), I can tell yo a web app is not a good fit for that, my recommendation would be either silverligth or some form of windows app

Now, communication between your app and the backend would definitely be web based, but the app itself is not a good idea

Comment: Now if your app is not THAT intensive, perhaps a web app could do the job; the image manipulation and dynamic zoning (different document formats) are the main reason to go wit the windows app